# .htaccess between developemt, staging, and production

Tags: php, .htaccess, development-environment

I'm working on a app that uses url rewrites and has a specific .htaccess configuration. When working on the app I have three eviorments:

1. Developent on my local machine (localhost)
2. Staging (staging.mydomain.com)
3. Production (www.mydomain.com)

I am constantly pushing new upgrades to the staging and production environment and each time I overwrite the existing source code I have to go in an change the .htaccess file. Is there a way I can the .htaccess generic to the directory or have it automatically detect it's environment?

My current .htaccess file is below. I just un-comment the sections between the different environments but would love to stop doing that...

```
# Development

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]

# Staging

# RewriteEngine on
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /html/app/index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]

# Production

# RewriteEngine on
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks in advance!

Chuck

Comment: Why are the paths differing, yet /favicon.ico is the same?

Comment: I'd just set up virtual hosts so you have the same URLs in each environment. Then you wouldn't need to change the .htaccess between them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
# Development

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]

# Staging

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /html/app/index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]

# Production

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Is `%{REQUEST_HOST}` outdated variable?  I only found the equivalent `%{HTTP_HOST}` in the mod_rewrite documentation.

Comment: @JohnnyWong, yep, seems so: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond
updated the answer with `HTTP_HOST` var.
Feel free to edit the answer in case you find any other issues, since I don't use apache since 2011 I think ;)

Answer (score 11):

One option would be to setup environment variables in `httpd.conf` (or elsewhere) that define your environment.

For example (in `httpd.conf`):

```
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT production
```

(in `.htaccess`)

```
RewriteEngine on

# Development
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} != /favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} = development
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]

# Staging
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} != /favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} = staging
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /html/app/index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]

# Production
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} != /favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} = production
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Untested, but I think the concept is sound enough to figure out any issues ;-)

Comment: +1 Great if you have access to Apache conf because you can then set the environment regardless of what the URL is. Makes local development where you use a different URL to hosted servers much easier

Answer (score 2):

Can you not just place your `.htaccess` files on each of the environments, and then just ignore the file in whatever FTP or deploy program you're using?

Alternative, what I do is set up `VirtualHosts` in my local host that is the same domain as the production site, but with a `dev.` prefix. For example, `www.example.com` and `dev.example.com`. That way, I can always be certain that the root is the top-level directory of whatever host I'm using, no matter the environment; and I don't need to re-write my `.htaccess` directives.

Answer (score 0):

Chuck D, the variant of Dumitru Ceban is very good. But I suggest you to try also option to have some flag in your code -- not in .htacces.

Also, good suggestion of rudi_visser. But I want to add here, that in the ideal system we should only use apache`s *.conf and decline .htaccess (just a stupid performance).

So I suggest you to have some flag in code, avoid .htacess (if you can) and switch env. by simple conf value or by some logic like `if locaslhost == host then ...`

Comment: Or for ideal system we just could use only-*.conf on production.

Comment: I don't think the performance of .htaccess on modern systems is anything to worry about anymore! But anyway I don't think putting this logic into code would help in this situation due to the fact that Apache won't know where to route the requests anyway.

Comment: @rudi_visser, not sure, that .htaccess is adequate on production. And PHP could know where to pass which logic inside your framework: which DB connection of tmp/pathes to use.

Comment: Ah yes for stuff like that, but I mean the main routing to index.php obviously couldn't be done in index.php itself, I thought that's what you meant :-) But again, if an environment variable was to be set as per my suggestion, you could use that within PHP to determine what action to take too!

Comment: The best practice I think would be a deploy script (like capistrano) which deploys the application code and just symlink the right htaccess file based on the environment you deploy to.

Comment: Also good. But I still suggest not to use .htaccess for production. Staging and dev -- ok, but not on production.