# Method of using .htaccess to Rewrite Server-Specific URLs is not obeying RewriteCond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to set up a my development, staging, and production servers in such a way that I can create a single `.htaccess` file and use environment-specific variables to determine which rewrite actions to execute.  I want to use the name of the specific server to do URL rewrites, but I seem to be running across some problem (likely trivial) that I simply can't solve.

The goal of this `.htaccess` file is to:

- Rewrite URL to WWW on production server only
- Send `.html` filenames as `foo` query vars
- Send `.htm` filenames as `bar` query vars
- Be able to modify or add additional rules to specific servers

Similar to [this suggested outline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6764470/102067), my htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# Production

# Redirect to WWW on production server
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html index.php?foo=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.htm index.php?bar=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Staging
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =staging.domain.com [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html index.php?foo=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(.+)\.htm index.php?bar=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Development
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html index.php?foo=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.htm index.php?bar=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

The problem that I'm having is that no matter which order I list the servers in the .htaccess file, only the first server listed seems to rewrite properly.  When deployed on the other servers I am noticing that the `foo` test case is skipped over and is instead returned as the `bar` result.  I have been able to determine that this seems to be coming from the second `RewriteRule` in the first server section, but I can't figure out why.

More information can be provided upon request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think maybe you need to replace the SERVER_NAME checks with HTTP_HOST and add a **$** to your html/htm checks.

```
# Redirect to WWW on production server
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?foo=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.htm$ index.php?bar=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

# Staging
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^staging\.domain\.com$ [NC]
# otherwise, it would look same as Development

# Development
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ index.php?foo=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.htm$ index.php?bar=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Great catch on the `$` at the html/htm checks.  I was able to keep `%{SERVER_NAME}` like I originally suggested as opposed to `%{HTTP_HOST}` like you mentioned.  Any reason why I shouldn't use this and should follow your suggestion instead?

Comment: If it works for you, there's probably no compelling reason for you to need to change them to `HTTP_HOST`. But because `SERVER_NAME` is a server internal that [takes its value from the UseCanonicalName directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) as opposed to `HTTP_HOST` which is a request header that the browser supplies based on what domain it thinks it's supposed to be talking to, sometimes they aren't interchangeable depending on someone's specific server configuration.

Comment: Appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Please be aware that `RewriteCond` only applies to **the next** `RewriteRule`. Lines 9 and 20 in this example (which looks for `.htm` files) are not targeted by your conditions.