# Single htaccess file with distinction between production and development

Tags: apache, .htaccess, development-environment

I am currently using two .htaccess files for my website: one is the development version, and the other one is the production version. The difference is in absolute and some relative paths that are used for `RedirectMatch`, `RewriteRule`, and `ErrorDocument` directives, and that differ between development and production. I am using a git hook to remove the dev version and rename the production version, but this still means I have to maintain two versions of basically the same file. Also, I am encountering similar problems with other sites I manage, so this all means more work. I rather have one single file and some sort of condition in the .htaccess file that allows me to say `if production -> use these, else -> use these`. Can I do such thing in an .htaccess file?

I have found this:

[.htaccess between developemt, staging, and production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764237/htaccess-between-developemt-staging-and-production)

But this is for rewrite rules and would not fix the different ErrorDocument paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your servers are running Apache 2.3 or higher, you can use an `<if expr>` directive like this:

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'dev.example.com'">
    # dev directives
</if>
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.example.com'">
    # prod directives
</if>
```

Earlier versions of Apache will throw a 500 Server Error if you use `<if>`, be sure to check the Apache version before trying this.

Comment: Note that in some cases this doesn't work because of the order in which the sections were merged - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging. Consider using `<IfDefine>` ( https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifdefine ) instead

Answer (score 3):

I ran into an issue where I needed a similar solution but could not use `<if expr>` directive because I was running Apache 2.2

An alternative is to **put password protect instruction in your apache config (vhost-conf in my case) file within the  tag like below.  Note that you still need a .hpasswd file**

```
ServerAdmin xxx@lami.me
DocumentRoot "/doc/root/html"

ServerName dev.lami.me
ServerAlias dev.lami.me localhost

ErrorLog "/doc/root/logs/error_log"
CustomLog "/doc/root/logs/access_log" common

<Directory "/doc/root/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthName "Restricted Area" 
    AuthType Basic 
    AuthUserFile /doc/root/.htpasswd 
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
    require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I rather have one single file and some sort of condition in the .htaccess file that allows me to say if production -> use these, else -> use these. Can I do such thing in an .htaccess file?

No.  Sorry.

However you *may* construct your .htaccess to work on both with a bit of care. And I have done this for my test and prod systems.

IMO, the easiest way to do this is to make your development site mirror your production site in some key aspects and this is what I do.  For example if your prod domain is mydomain.com and your test environment is on localhost, the add an alias of mydomain.home for localhost in your etc/hosts file.  You can now add a vhost for mydomain.home and mirror the document roots and environment setting of prod in this.  If you need to refer to the HTTP_HOST, you can now use mydomain.(com|home) and use %1 to distinguish which.

This assumes that you are running your dev env on a LAMP system.  If not it's pretty easy to set up a VM to do this (as I describe [here](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/article-61))

You can use RewriteRules instead of RedirectMatch directives and with Rewriterules you can use the [C],[OR],[E] and [S] flags to implement branch-style ladder-logic which can effectively mirror if/then/else constructs.

The main gotcha is DocumentRoot setting if you production is on a shared hosting environment and with impacts local ErrorDocument paths, but without knowing you environments, it is difficult to give more specifics

Comment: @user1162541,  Yes A2.4 has the <if> directive which is a neater approach, but beware that few hosting service providers will have adopted A2.4 yet, as it still has performance and stability issues.