# Trying to set up a heroku staging site - "Resource not found "

Tags: git, heroku, staging

I'm working on an existing rails project which is deployed on heroku.  I'm trying to set up a staging server which deploys from the staging branch.  (currently master deploys to production).

I'm following this page 
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#starting_with_a_production_app

and i'm on the section "Starting from a production app".  The code it gives is

`heroku create --stack [production stack] --remote staging --addons newrelic:bronze,logging:expanded`

I'm trying to adapt this to my own needs but i get a message back `Resource not found`.

Here's what i get for "heroku apps"

```
custom_domains:basic
exceptional:basic
logging:expanded
shared-database:5mb
```

If i do `heroku list` i get this

```
buddystef                 <project manager's email>
vivid-window-286
vivid-earth-537
```

where 'buddystef' is the production version of the app.  So, i'm trying this:

`heroku create --stack [buddystef stack] --remote buddy-staging --addons custom_domains:basic,exceptional:basic,logging:expanded,shared-database:5mb`

And i'm getting `Resource not found`

Do i need to set up a seperate git repo first for the staging branch?  If so, what's the best way to do this?

Grateful for any advice - max

EDIT - the "Resource not found" message seems (after googling) to be associated with logging in with the wrong credentials.  But, i'm logging in as the owner of the buddystef project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your over-complicating things here, Max. Keep it simple, create the app like John suggests, add the addons, then declare it a staging environment:

```
heroku config:add RACK_ENV=staging --app stagingbuddystef
```

create the `environments/staging.rb` similar to that of `production.rb`

If it's a public site, you'd probably wish to secure it from public access, avoid confusing users. See this [SO answer for password protecting staging environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482266/password-protecting-a-rails-staging-environment/5565237#5565237)

**Git** : You should have your own staging branch. Remember that heroku operates on master branch, so you should do this:

```
myproj git:(staging)$ git push stagingbuddystef staging:master
```

Read more about git *good* practices here: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: Max does this mean that you abandoned the official Heroku methodology in the end? I've been having the same problems you did

Answer (score 1):

Heroku create with stack synxtax is

```
heroku create test-sushi-app --stack bamboo-mri-1.9.2
```

where bamboo-mri-1.9.2 can be any of the following:

- aspen-mri-1.8.6
- bamboo-ree-1.8.7
- bamboo-mri-1.9.2

so I'm no sure where your `[buddystef stack]` comes from but that's likely the problem

Answer (score 0):

I use Heroku San, which does some of the legwork for you. [Github](https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san) | [Tutorial](http://jqr.github.com/2010/08/27/easy-heroku-deploys-with-heroku-san.html)