# "Resource not found" for Heroku PG commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resources, pg

I got a free Heroku account and I'm working with:

- Rails 3.2.8
- Heroku heroku-toolbelt/2.33.2
- PG

But, each time I'm typing a Heroku PG commands, I got this message:

```
Resource not found!
```

Except for the credentials command:

```
➜  heroku pg:credentials HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MYDB
   Connection info string:
   "dbname=blahblahblah"
```

Else, all others command fail:

```
➜  heroku pg:info HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MYDB       
   !    Resource not found

➜  heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MYDB    
   WARNING: Destructive Action
   This command will affect the app: myapp
   To proceed, type "myapp" or re-run this command with --confirm myapp

   > myapp
   Resetting HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MYDB_URL (DATABASE_URL)... failed
   !    Resource not found
➜
```

Any ideas ?
If you need more information, tell me :)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you fix it? I'm having the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Previously, there was some [issue](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/368) with heroku gem version(2.26.6) and this Resource not found occurred, but it gets fixed in the latest versions.

There is no problem with the current version what you are using.

Your heroku keys will be invalid([Trying to set up a heroku staging site - "Resource not found "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937725/trying-to-set-up-a-heroku-staging-site-resource-not-found)).

If it is correct, you need to downgrade the heroku gem and check it.

Please follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820549/how-to-empty-db-in-heroku).

It will help you to fix the above issue.